# How can I fix matrix multiplication between two matrices of different column lengths?

Tags: c++, matrix

So currently I have my matrix class that can multiply between two matrices of the same row length / column length but are unable to multiply properly with different column lengths.

```cpp
int main() {
    
    // defaults to Matrix<float, 4, 4> a 4x4 matrix
    Matrix a(1.0f);
    
    // 4x1 matrix
    Matrix<float, 4, 1> b;
    
    b(0) = 0.1f;
    b(1) = 0.1f;
    b(2) = 0.1f;
    b(3) = 1.0f;
    
    cout << a << '\n';
    /* 
    [1 0 0 0]
    [0 1 0 0]
    [0 0 1 0]
    [0 0 0 1]
    */
    
    cout << b << '\n';
    /* 
    [0.1]
    [0.1]
    [0.1]
    [1]
    */
    
    cout << a * b << '\n';
    // Expected this message which is good
    // 4x4 matrix * 4x1 matrix = 4x1 matrix
    /* 
    
    However the log I expected for a * b was this:
    [0.1]
    [0.1]
    [0.1]
    [1.0]
    
    But got:
    [0.1]
    [0]
    [0]
    [0]
    */
    
    Matrix c;
    c(0) = 0.1f;
    c(1) = 0.1f;
    c(2) = 0.1f;
    c(3) = 1.0f;
    
    cout << a * c << '\n';
    /* 
    Multiplication between 2 matrices of the
    same row/column length work as expected
    [0.1 0 0 0]
    [0.1 0 0 0]
    [0.1 0 0 0]
    [1 0 0 0]
    */
}
```

The multiplication code, matrix multiplication of 2 matrices of the same row/column length work as expected but multiplication with different column lengths don’t work as expected.

```cpp
template<typename T, unsigned int R = 4, unsigned int C = R, unsigned int F>
Matrix<T, R, F> operator*(const Matrix<T, R, C>& matrix, const Matrix<T, C, F>& other) {
    Matrix<T, R, F> r(0.0f);
    
    // logs matrix’s row/column length
    cout << R << "x" << C << " matrix";
    cout << " * ";

    // logs “other” matrix’s row/column length
    cout << C << "x" << F << " matrix";
    cout << " = ";

    // logs 'r'’s log and column length.
    cout << R << "x" << F << " matrix \n";

    // (i.e) 4x4 matrix * 4x1 matrix = 4x1 matrix
    // this is working as expected
    
    for (int row = 0; row < R; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < F; ++column) {
            for (int k = 0; k < F; ++k)
                // operator() was overload to access the private
                // matrix array
                r(row, column) += matrix(row, k) * other(k, column);
        } 
    }
    
    return r;
}
```

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. T is for the type. It defines the result matrix type of the first line of the function.

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k < C; ++k)` Try this!!

Comment: Sorry typo. I meant `C` not `T`.

Comment: I get [0.4 0.4 0.4 1.0] logged to the console now, it’s close to what I wanted.

Comment: Since you're returning a `Matrix` by value, any errors with this function would need to be accompanied by code verifying that `Matrix` has correct copy semantics.

Comment: The line `for (int k = 0; k < F; ++k)` is wrong. it needs to be `for (int k = 0; k < C; ++k)`

Comment: `0.4` could result from a bug in code that you didn't show.

Comment: Is `a` the identity matrix or the `all 1` matrix or something else ?

Comment: What I usually do (I get matrix operations wrong embarrassingly often) is to print the indices in every iteration and triple-check them against what they should be.